# Show Webform confirm message in my custom panel page

Tags: webforms

I'm new to Drupal. I have created a web form in my page using [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module. I added my contact web form in a custom panel page. I use the [Clientside Validation](https://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module to validate the web forms.

If the form validation is okay, I want to show the confirmation message at the top of the web form in my panel page instead of the default message location used in the page.tpl.php. I use the single page web site.

Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Comment: I would implement a single-page website by writing a custom module. It would reduce dependencies of other modules and make the site lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that the [Clientside Validation](https://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module shows the message in the default location defined in the template.

You can check [Clientside Validation Usage](https://drupal.org/node/1324924). Then you can see **Error Message placement** and **Default location**. I hope you can tweak your default message location from this:

> Here you can select the default location to display your error
>   messages. You can choose between the following options:
>
> - jQuery selector: This option will place a div containing all the    error messages inside the div that matches the jQuery selector
>     entered in the "jQuery selector" field below this option.
> - Top of form: This option will place a div containing all the error messages    above the form the error messages are for.
> - Before label: This option will place the error before the label of the matching element
> - Afterlabel: This option will place the error after the label of the    matching element
> - Before input: This option will place the error    before the matching element
> - After input: This option will place the error after the matching element
> - Top of first form: This option will    place a div containing all the error messages above the first form.    This means that when there
>     are multiple forms on a page, the errors    of the second form will be
>     added to the error div of the first form    and will be displayed
>     above the first form
> - Custom function: (Advanced) Selecting this option requires you to enter a javascript    function name in the textfield "Custom function
>     name" below this    option. This function name will be given to the
>     errorPlacement option    of jQuery.validate()

You could use jQuery selector or Custom function.